# i have problem with git, can you help mee

Tags: git, git-push

[image: This comes before.]

How can I delete everything in git and start from the beginning?
How do I push in this situation?

[image: This is what happens after...]

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

In git you first have to stage your changes, then commit your changes, and then push your changes to the remote repository.

The first command basically says that there is no main nor master branch on the remote.

Can you try to create one by `git branch -b master` for example. After that to get your changes on the remote repository you have to add a commit, and push this commit to the remote repository.

A normal routine to push new changes in git would be:

1. `git add .` (to stage all files) or `git add somefile.txt`
2. `git commit -m "Awesome changes"` where -m stands for the commit message.
3. `git push <your-remote-name> <your-branch-name>`
   in most scenario's you will only work with one remote, which is called `origin` most of the times. So the command would become `git push origin master` for instance.

Comment: Thanks bro for answering my question. I tried to do what you wrote me, but it didn't work. please I need your help for Git. how can we get in touch to resolve this issue?